# Can any JavaScript uglifier/minifier ignore part of a file?

Tags: javascript, minify, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs

I'm wondering whether any JavaScript uglifier can exclude **parts of** a file.

Like in this block, I only want it in the dev environment:

```
// If s is undefined warn the DEV guys they forgot something!
if(s === undefined)
    throw new Error('Invalid i18n key');
```

I can stop the error by adding a global var to the conditional, but it would be cool to just have it exclude the block with some metadata:

```
/* UGLIFY exclude */
// If s is undefined warn the DEV guys they forgot something!
if(path === undefined)
    throw new Error('Invalid i18n key, on' + current.parser.lineNo);
/* /UGLIFY */*
```

Is this possible with any of them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Grunt.js. Simply break out the part you don't want minified into a standalone file. Uglify the other file then concatenate the ugly file and the pretty file. Of course if you're keeping an `if` statement pretty, the precise location of that code is important (vs a function that gets hoisted). So, maybe you need to break out your script into 3 files to sandwich the pretty `if` in the middle, but this is doable.

If you want an easy Grunt getting started guide: https://hightechtele.com/articles/grunt-getting-started

Checking out [Grunt uglify documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#exceptionsfiles): (this may or may not be what your looking for too)

> exceptionsFiles Type: Array Default: []
>
> Use this with mangle.properties to pass one or more JSON files
>   containing a list of variables and object properties that should not
>   be mangled. See the UglifyJS docs for more info on the file syntax.